# Unofficial msgs tutorial - rosjava

Tags: ros, rosjava, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm going through the rosjava tutorials, and I'm running up against problems with making unofficial messages.

I followed all of the steps in section 2.1, but when I attempt to catkin_make, my build fails. I get the following:
.

```
(...)
:my_java_library:jar UP-TO-DATE
:foo_msgs:generateSources UP-TO-DATE
:foo_msgs:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:foo_msgs:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:foo_msgs:classes UP-TO-DATE
:foo_msgs:jar

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not copy MANIFEST.MF to '/home/team5/RSS-hydro/src/myjava_msgs/foo_msgs/build/tmp/jar/MANIFEST.MF'.
> A Jar can only accept a valid file or directory: /home/team5/RSS-hydro/src/myjava_msgs/foo_msgs/build/classes/main
```

I'm not sure what I need to do to fix this...have you seen it before? I've gotten through the Publisher/Listener tutorials, set up launch files, etc, so I thought that I was on the right track...but I have no clue where to run with this one.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/149601/unofficial-msgs-tutorial---rosjava/) by [viccro](https://answers.ros.org/users/14456/viccro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just following up on here with what I posed to the rosjava sig group. I suspect this means you haven't created, or don't have the real foo_msgs package on your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. If that's correct, I probably need to add this point more explicitly on the tutorial.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2014-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0